# Looping json data dynamically in Python

Tags: python, json, loops

I have a two json file in a server. The first json file is a dataframe in json format where it is having 21 columns.

The second json object is a collection of different filters to be applied on the first json(data file) & I want to calculate the reduction in amount column dynamically after applying each filter.

Both the jsons are in server. Sample of this is like below,

```
[{
        "criteria_no.": 1,
        "expression": "!=",
        "attributes": "Industry_name",
        "value": "Clasentrix"

    },{ 
        "criteria_no.": 2,
        "expression": "=",
        "attributes": "currency",
        "value": ["EUR","GBP","INR"]


    },{
        "criteria_no.": 3,
        "expression": ">",
        "attributes": "Industry_Rating",
        "value": "A3"

    },{
        "criteria_no.": 4,
        "expression": "<",
        "attributes": "Due_date",
        "value": "01/01/2025"

    }
    ]
```

When coded in python, it is like below,

```
import urllib2, json
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://.../server/criteria_sample.json')
obj = json.load(url)
print obj

[{u'attributes': u'Industry_name', u'expression': u'!=', u'value': u'Clasentrix', u'criteria_no.': 1}, {u'attributes': u'currency', u'expression': u'=', u'value': [u'EUR', u'GBP', u'INR'], u'criteria_no.': 2}, {u'attributes': u'Industry_Rating', u'expression': u'>', u'value': u'A3', u'criteria_no.': 3}, {u'attributes': u'Due_date', u'expression': u'<', u'value': u'01/01/2025', u'criteria_no.': 4}]
```

Now, in the sample json, we can see `"attributes"`, which are nothing but the columns present in the first data file. I mentioned it has 21 columns, `"Industry_name"`,`"currency"`,`"Industry_Rating"`,`"Due_date"` are four of them. `"Loan_amount"` is another column present there in the data file along with all them.

Now as this criteria list is only a sample, we are having n number of such criterion or filters. I want this filters to be applied dynamically on the data file & I would like to calculate the reduction in loan amount. Let's consider the first filter, it is saying `"Industry_name"` column should not have `"Clasentrix"`. So from the data file I want to filter `"Industry_name"`, which will not have `'Clasentrix'` entry. Now let's say for 11 observations we had `'Clasentrix'` out of 61 observations from the data file. Then we will take sum of entire loan amount(61 rows) & then subtract the sum of loan amount for 11 rows which consist `'Clasentrix'` from the total loan amount. This number will be considered as reduction for after applying the first filter.

Now for each of n criterion I want to calculate the reduction dynamically in python. So inside the loop the filter json file will create filter considering attribute, expression & value. Just like for the first filter it is `"Industry_name != 'Clasentrix'"`. This should get reflected for each set of rows for the json object like for the second criterion(filter) it should be `"currency=['EUR','GBP','INR']"` & so on. I also want to calculate the reduction accordingly.

I am struggling to create the python code for the above mentioned exercise. My post is too long, apologies for that. But please provide assistance that how can I calculate the reduction dynamically for each n criterion.

Thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE** for first data file, find some sample rows;

```
[{
        "industry_id.": 1234,
        "loan_id": 1113456,
        "Industry_name": "Clasentrix",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "Industry_Rating": "Ba3",
        "Due_date": "20/02/2020",
        "loan_amount": 563332790,
        "currency_rate": 0.67,
        "country": "USA"


    },{ 
        "industry_id.": 6543,
        "loan_id": 1125678,
        "Industry_name": "Wolver",
        "currency": "GBP",
        "Industry_Rating": "Aa3",
        "Due_date": "23/05/2020",
        "loan_amount": 33459087,
        "currency_rate": 0.8,
        "country": "UK"


    },{
        "industry_id.": 1469,
        "loan_id": "8876548",
        "Industry_name": "GroupOn",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "Industry_Rating": "Aa1",
        "Due_date": "16/09/2021",
        "loan_amount": 66543278,
        "currency_rate": 0.67,
        "country": "UK"
    },{
        "industry_id.": 1657,
        "loan_id": "6654321",
        "Industry_name": "Clasentrix",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "Industry_Rating": "Ba3",
        "Due_date": "15/07/2020",
        "loan_amount": 5439908765,
        "currency_rate": 0.53,
        "country": "USA"

    }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data flie as well?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you able to load all the json data into memory, or is the data file very large? [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) might be useful.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I have updated my question with a sample of the data file as well

Comment: @Stuart, the json files are loaded in the server. I was able to load them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pandas to turn the json data into a dataframe and turn the criteria into [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-query) strings. Some processing is needed to turn the criteria json into a valid query. In the code below dates are still treated as strings - you may need to explicitly set date queries to convert the string into a date first.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
# ...
criteria = json.load(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(data_url)) # data_url is the handle of the data file
print("Loan total without filters is {}".format(df["loan_amount"].sum()))

for c in criteria:
    if c["expression"] == "=":
        c["expression"] = "=="

    # If the value is a string we need to surround it in quotation marks
    # Note this can break if any values contain "
    if isinstance(c["value"], basestring):
        query = '{attributes} {expression} "{value}"'.format(**c)
    else:
        query = '{attributes} {expression} {value}'.format(**c)
    loan_total = df.query(query)["loan_amount"].sum()
    print "With criterion {}, {}, loan total is {}".format(c["criteria_no."], query, loan_total)
```

Alternatively you can turn each criterion into an indexing vector like this:

```
def criterion_filter(s, expression, value):
    if type(value) is list:
        if expression == "=":
            return s.isin(value)
        elif expression == "!=":
            return ~s.isin(value)
    else:
        if expression == "=":
            return s == value
        elif expression == "!=":
            return s != value
        elif expression == "<":
            return s < value
        elif expression == ">":
            return s > value        

for c in criteria:
    filt = criterion_filter(df[c["attributes"]], c["expression"], c["value"])
    loan_total = df[filt]["loan_amount"].sum()
    print "With criterion {}, loan total is {}".format(c["criteria_no."],  loan_total)
```

EDIT: To calculate the cumulative reduction in loan total, you can combine the indexing vectors using the & operator.

```
loans = [df["loan_amount"].sum()]
print("Loan total without filters is {}".format(loans[0]))
filt = True
for c in criteria:
    filt &= criterion_filter(df[c["attributes"]], c["expression"], c["value"])
    loans.append(df[filt]["loan_amount"].sum())
    print "Adding criterion {} reduces the total by {}".format(c["criteria_no."],
        loans[-2] - loans[-1])
    print "The cumulative reduction is {}".format(loans[0] - loans[-1])
```

Comment: Great answer Stuart. Helped me a lot. Just couple of things;

1.
for c in criteria:
    locator = criterion_filter(df[c["attributes"]], c["expression"], c["value"])
    loan_total = df[locator]["loan_amount"].sum()
    print "With criterion {}, loan total is {}".format(c["criteria_no."],  loan_total)

is giving me the reduced loan amount after applying criterion. But want the reductions figures only to be reflected. I mean if the total loan_amount was 100, & after applying criteria1 the revised loan_amount is 90, the reduction is 100-90=10. I want this '10' to be calculated.

Comment: & 2,
if I also want to calculate the cumulative reduction, how that can be done? I mean after applying two criterion together, what is the total reduction figure? That also should be dynamic, I mean the code should calculate after applying n criterion together, what is the cumulative reduction, whatever be the value of n.

How to incorporate that cumulative part also in that code? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I have figured out the calculation for the first one. Please help me to calculate the cumulative reduction. I mean when m of n criterion(n>m) applied together, how the code will calculate the reduction?

Comment: See edits for applying cumulative criteria and calculating the stepwise and total reduction in loan value